# SMS Broadcast receiver doesn't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I tried popping a Toast when the user I getting an SMS message.
for some reason, the Toast doesn't show
I have every permission I need in the manifest file

[the receiver in manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X0Wu.png)

the code:

```
   public class IncomingSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"don't let your SMS keep you away from your missions goal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are multiple causes for this, one of which is that your app is lower broadcast priority than other installed SMS apps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permissions in the manifest file.
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>`
Use like this

```
<receiver
android:name=".SmsBroadReceiver"
android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" 
   />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>`
```

Comment: I did .. and also RECIEVR_SMS

Comment: add this  `android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
`

Comment: "permission is only granted to system apps"

Comment: not in <uses-permission> but do it for your broadcast reciever

Comment: "tag start is not closed" i didnt really get where i should write it